# Matplotlib subplots kills Jupyter kernel

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to set up a custom conda environment for the first time. I'm running Python 3.8 with numpy, matplotlib, jupyter, tensorflow, and all their dependencies, on 64 bit Windows 10.

When I try to run the following to plot an image, it reaches the first two print statements before crashing the kernel, indicating that the plt.subplot is causing the issue.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print("importing isn't the problem")

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
print("figure isn't the problem")
for images, labels in train_ds.take(1):
  for i in range(9):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    print("subplots isn't the problem")
    plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    print("imshow isn't the problem")
    plt.axis("off")
    print("axis isn't the problem")
```

I've found others who have had this problem, who determined that it was caused by the freetype package having updated to version 2.11.0, with the fix being to downgrade back to version 2.10.4. However, it tells me my freetype version for this environment is 2.10.4, so I'm not sure what else to do to fix it.

Additional info which may be helpful: I did all the environment creation and setup in Anaconda Navigator because I'm new to managing conda environments and I'm not super comfortable with the command line just yet. I installed Anaconda back in June or July of this year. I've been able to use matplotlib in jupyter notebooks in the base environment that was setup on install without issue. I can't upgrade to Python 3.9- I need to use 3.8 for parity with a project partner.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and it disappeared with no changes.
Heisenbug. - Disappears when you measure it but not necessarily immediately.

I isolated the function that was faulty.

I isolated the line that was faulty.

I reproduced the error.

Came back the next day, and the problem had disappeared with no changes.
Maybe that'll happen to you(?).